# Trying to use setInterval inside a scheduleJob and it doesn't work

Tags: discord.js, setinterval

I'm having this the following code, and I'm trying to use a function inside setInterval but it just won't work... what I'm doing wrong?

```js
const job = schedule.scheduleJob({ hour: 01, minute: 56 }, () => {
    loop();
});

function loop() {
    var checkminutes = 5,
        checkthe_interval = checkminutes * 60 * 1000;
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        i++;
        console.log(i); // Just trying here to see if the i value gets printed in console.. but nope..
        //uploadFile();
    }, checkthe_interval);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please clarify further with what you mean when you say it won't work? What is the result?

Comment: It doesn't prints in console the value i, it literally skips that part

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: idk if this work or not but try replace checkthe_interval variable with `6960000`

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove the last 2 lines from the code in order to make it work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).